# React react-bootstrap TypeError: this.state is null

Tags: reactjs

The project is a Django React project. I want to add and edit employees. To display the employees is working fine. I tried already several different solution which I found in the www but I can not solve the issue.

I do not understand why the warning occurres on the console: `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`
I have a key={} in the  tag. Does the AddEmployee.jsx or EditEmployee.jsx file do not have access to the DepartmentId and DepartmentName? How can I check this if the files has just no access to these?

What I have tried, I can not really remember... I changed the Form.Controle to Form.Select in EditEmployee.jsx. In AddEmployee.jsx I have not changed the code so you can see the previous version.

Employee.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';

import { Button, ButtonToolbar } from 'react-bootstrap';

import AddEmployee from './AddEmployee';
import EditEmployee from './EditEmployee';


export default class Employee extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={employees:[], addEmployee:false, editEmployee:false};
    }

    refreshList() {
        fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API+'employee/')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({employees:data});
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.refreshList();
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.refreshList();
    }

    deleteEmployee(employeeid) {
        if(window.confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API+'employee/'+employeeid, {
                method:'DELETE',
                header:{'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
    const { employees, employeeid, employeename, department, photo, datejoining } = this.state;
    let addEmployeeClose = () => this.setState({addEmployee:false});
    let editEmployeeClose = () => this.setState({editEmployee:false});

        return (
            <div>
                <Table 
                    className="mt-4" 
                    striped bordered hover size="sm">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Employee Id</th>
                            <th>Employee Name</th>
                            <th>Department</th>
                            <th>Joining Date</th>
                            <th>Options</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        {employees.map(emp => 
                            <tr key = {emp.EmployeeId}>
                                <td>{emp.EmployeeId}</td>
                                <td>{emp.EmployeeName}</td>
                                <td>{emp.Department}</td>
                                <td>{emp.DateOfJoining}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <ButtonToolbar>
                                        <Button
                                            className="mr-2"
                                            variant="info"
                                            onClick={() => this.setState(
                                                {editEmployee:true, 
                                                    employeeid:emp.EmployeeId, 
                                                    employeename:emp.EmployeeName,
                                                    department:emp.Department,
                                                    photo:emp.PhotoFileName,
                                                    datejoining:emp.DateOfJoining})}>
                                                Edit
                                        </Button>

                                        <Button
                                            className="mr-2"
                                            variant="danger"
                                            onClick={() => this.deleteEmployee(emp.EmployeeId)}>
                                                Delete
                                        </Button>

                                        <EditEmployee
                                            show={this.state.editEmployee}
                                            onHide={editEmployeeClose}
                                            employeeid={employeeid}
                                            employeename={employeename}
                                            department={department}
                                            photo={photo}
                                            datejoining={datejoining} />
                                    </ButtonToolbar>
                                </td>
                            </tr>)}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>

                <ButtonToolbar>
                    <Button 
                        variant="primary"
                        onClick= {() => this.setState({addEmployee:true})}>
                            Add Employee
                    </Button>

                    <AddEmployee 
                        show={this.state.addEmployee}
                        onHide={addEmployeeClose} />
                </ButtonToolbar>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

EditEmplyee.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Modal, Button, Row, Col, Form, Image } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class EditEmployee extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API+'employee', {
            method:'PUT',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'applications/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
                EmployeeId:event.target.EmployeeID.value,
                EmployeeName:event.target.EmployeeName.value,
                Department:event.target.Department.value,
                DateOfJoining:event.target.DateOfJoining.value,
                PhotoFileName:this.photo
            })
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
            alert(result);
        },
        (error) => {
            alert('Failed');
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <Modal
                    {...this.props}
                    size="lg"
                    aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vecenter"
                    centered
                >
                    <Modal.Header cloosebutton="true">
                        <Modal.Title 
                            id="contained-modal-title-vecenter">
                                Edit Employee 
                        </Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>

                    <Modal.Body>
                        <Row>
                            <Col sm={6}>
                                <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                    <Form.Group controlId="EmployeeId">
                                        <Form.Label>Employee Id</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control 
                                            type="text" 
                                            name="EmployeeId" 
                                            required 
                                            disabled
                                            defaultValue = {this.props.employeeid}
                                            placeholder="Employee Id"/>
                                    </Form.Group>

                                    <Form.Group controlId="EmployeeName">
                                        <Form.Label>Employee Name</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control 
                                            type="text" 
                                            name="EmployeeName" 
                                            required 
                                            defaultValue = {this.props.employeename}
                                            placeholder="Employee Name"/>
                                    </Form.Group>

                                    <Form.Group controlId="Department">
                                        <Form.Label>Department</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Select 
                                            defaultValue = {this.props.department}
                                        >                                       
                                            
                                                {this.state.departments.map(dep => (
                                                <option 
                                                    key={dep.DepartmentId} 
                                                    value={dep.DepartmentName} 
                                                />
                                            ))
                                            }

                                            
                                        </Form.Select>
                                    </Form.Group>

                                    <Form.Group controlId="DateOfJoining">
                                        <Form.Label>Joined Date</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control 
                                            type="date"
                                            name="DateOfJoining"
                                            required
                                            defaultValue = {this.props.datejoining}
                                            placeholder="Joining Date"
                                        />
                                    </Form.Group>

                                    <Form.Group>
                                        <Button 
                                            variant="primary" 
                                            type="submit">
                                                Update Employee
                                        </Button>
                                    </Form.Group>
                                </Form>
                            </Col>

                            <Col sm={6}>
                                <Image 
                                    width="200px"
                                    height="200px"
                                    src={process.env.REACT_APP_PHOTOPATH+this.props.photo} 
                                />
                                <input onChange={this.handleFileSelected} type="File" />
                            </Col>

                        </Row>
                    </Modal.Body>

                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button 
                            variant="danger" 
                            onClick={this.props.onHide}>
                                Close
                        </Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
            </div>
            )
    }
}
```

AddEmplyee.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Modal, Button, Row, Col, Form, Image } from 'react-bootstrap';


export default class AddEmployee extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={departments:[]}
        this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleFileSelected=this.handleFileSelected.bind(this);
    }

    photo = 'book.png';
    imagesrc = process.env.REACT_APP_PHOTOPATH+this.photo;

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API+'employee/')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({departments:data});
        });
    }


    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API+'employee/', {
            method:'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'applications/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
                EmployeeId:null,
                EmployeeName:event.target.EmployeeName.value,
                Department:event.target.Department.value,
                DateOfJoining:event.target.DateOfJoining.value,
                PhotoFileName:this.photo
            })
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
            alert(result);
        },
        (error) => {
            alert('Failed');
        })
    }

    handleFileSelected(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.photo=event.target.files[0].name;
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append(
            "myFile",
            event.target.files[0],
            event.target.files[0].name
        );

        fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API+'employee/saveFile', {
            method:'POST',
            body:formData
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
            this.imagesrc=process.env.REACT_APP_PHOTOPATH+result;
        },
        (error) => {
            alert('Failed');
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <Modal
                    {...this.props}
                    size="lg"
                    aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vecenter"
                    centered
                >
                    <Modal.Header cloosebutton="true">
                        <Modal.Title 
                            id="contained-modal-title-vecenter">
                                Add Employee 
                        </Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>

                    <Modal.Body>
                        <Row>
                            <Col sm={6}>
                                <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                    <Form.Group controlId="EmployeeName">
                                        <Form.Label>Employee Name</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control 
                                            type="text" 
                                            name="EmployeeName" 
                                            required 
                                            placeholder="Employee Name"/>
                                    </Form.Group>

                                    <Form.Group controlId="Department">
                                        <Form.Label>Department</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control as="select">
                                            {this.state.departments.map((dep) =>
                                                <option key={dep.DepartmentId} >
                                                    {dep.DepartmentName}
                                                </option>
                                            )};
                                        </Form.Control>
                                    </Form.Group>

                                    <Form.Group controlId="DateOfJoining">
                                        <Form.Label>Joined Date</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control 
                                            type="date"
                                            name="DateOfJoining"
                                            required
                                            placeholder="Joining Date"
                                        />
                                    </Form.Group>

                                    <Form.Group>
                                        <Button 
                                            variant="primary" 
                                            type="submit">
                                                Add Employee
                                        </Button>
                                    </Form.Group>
                                </Form>
                            </Col>

                            <Col sm={6}>
                                <Image 
                                    width="200px"
                                    height="200px"
                                    src={this.imagesrc} 
                                />
                                <input onChange={this.handleFileSelected} type="File" />
                            </Col>

                        </Row>
                    </Modal.Body>

                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button 
                            variant="danger" 
                            onClick={this.props.onHide}>
                                Close
                        </Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
            </div>
            )
    }
}
```

console:
[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no state inside EditEmplyee.jsx ? I see you send from props departments to EditEmployee. use `this.props.departments`

Also check your id's (key). are there really unique?.

Comment: I add the state like in AddEmployee.jsx and now The page is displaying. But I still can not add an emplyee because the department drop down is not working. The department drop down is empty. Yes, the DepartmentID is unique.